# Unable to extract noun pharses from the result of open nlp Chunking parser

Tags: java, parsing, opennlp, chunking

Hi i have used openNLP chunking Parser and parsed some text and with the help of below stack overflow question i have tried to extract only noun phrases

[How to extract the noun phrases using Open nlp's chunking parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14708047/how-to-extract-the-noun-phrases-using-open-nlps-chunking-parser)

But i was unable to extract noun phrases, below is my code

```
public class keywords {
    List<Parse> nounPhrases;
    public static void main(String args[])throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("en-parser-chunking.bin");

        ParserModel model = new ParserModel(is);

        opennlp.tools.parser.Parser parser = ParserFactory.create(model);

        String sentence = "Programcreek is a very huge and useful website";
        Parse topParses[] = ParserTool.parseLine(sentence, parser, 1);

        for (Parse p : topParses)
        {
            p.show();
            p.toString();
        }
        is.close();

    }
    public void getNounPhrases(Parse p) {
        if (p.getType().equals("NP")) {
             nounPhrases.add(p);
        }
        for (Parse child : p.getChildren()) {
             getNounPhrases(child);
        }
    }

}
```

Please suggest me in extracting NP from parsed content

Thanks

Comment: Your code works... you just need to actually _call_ `getNounPhrases(p)` (and initialize `nounPhrases`).

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the string in token format like the below:

```
new String[]{"Programcreek ",
             "is",
             "a",
             "very",
             "huge",
             };
```